# SQL distant relationship

Tags: sql, relationship

We have 3 tables

1. order
2. customer
3. customerType

To access all order according to customer type, should we use intermediate table as stated in exampl-1 or should we use foreign key in order table stated in example-2 which one is best?

Example 1:

customerType

```
id - integer
name - string
```

customer

```
id - integer
customertype_id - integer
name - string
```

order

```
id - integer
customer_id - integer
orderNo - string
```

Example 2:

customerType

```
id - integer
name - string
```

customer

```
id - integer
customertype_id - integer
name - string
```

order

```
id - integer
customer_id - integer
orderNo - string
customerType_id -string
```

Example 1 or Example 2 ? In terms of performance.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is relation between customer and type? `1` to `n`? `1` to `1`?

Answer (score 2):

There should be no reason in modern relational databases to put `customerType` in the `order` table (unless the type of customer can be different between different orders of the same customer, of course).  Query optimization will remove any advantages, and you will use less database space.